# how add logical negation(!) operator in dynamic html

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

how to add negation operator in dynamic html content

```
'<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 form-group1" ng-class="{\'has-error\': (form.Year.$error.required && form.Year.$touched), \'has-success\':  !(form.Year.$error.required)}"><select ng-model="year" class="form-control" ' + strAttrs[2] + ' ng-options="year.value as year.name disable when year.disabled for year in years" class="form-control" ng-required="true" name="Year"></select></div>'
```

In this above code i have given negation operator like this,

> !(form.Year.$error.required)

but every time it is taking null,I guess I have not added logical operator proper in dynamic html content.

Any help is appreciable, Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: is `select` element wrap with `form` with `name="form"`..?

Comment: Yes, Actually I am adding creating angular directive, and in that i am writing dynamic stuff, based or ng-required it should select, 'ng-error' or 'ng-success' class.

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me:

`<div ng-class="{'ok': (success && !error), 'not-ok': (!success || error)}">Result Box</div>`

Note that I did not need to escape the single quotes.  When I tried escaping the single quotes it did not work.

I also noticed some invalid quoting going on in your select:

`class="form-control" ' + strAttrs[2] + ' ng-options="year.value as year.name disable when year.disabled for year in years"`

You also define the class twice, but that should just fail silently.

Here's a tiny working example:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
  <script>
  angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller('MyController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
        $scope.success = true;
        $scope.error = false;
    }]);
  </script>
  <style>
    .not-ok { border: 1px solid red; }
    .ok { background-color: green; }
  </style>
</head>
<body ng-controller="MyController">
  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="success">Success {{success}}
  <br/>
  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="error">Error {{error}}
  <div ng-class="{'ok': (success && !error), 'not-ok': (!success || error)}">Result Box</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yup it is working in that way for me too, but i am creating some dynamic stuff

Say I have to create a dynamic html like 

    var test = '<div ng-class="{'ok': (success && !error), 'not-ok': (!success || error)}">Result Box</div>';

in this case it won't work, so far that reason i used backslash